# ASP.NET Membership Password Reset

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership, membership-provider, sqlmembershipprovider

This is crazy, I have been trying for hours to get this to work.

My client wants to be able to reset password for users who have forgotten them The only parameter he has is the UserName.
He does NOT want the user to be able to reset the password themselves, no that would be too easy...ARGHHHHH!!

Anyway, if anyone has any suggestions how I could reset someones password or give them a new temp password somehow, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(username);
mu.ChangePassword(mu.ResetPassword(), password);
```

Here's a [link](http://peterkellner.net/2007/02/15/resetpasswordaspnet/) that does this (with above code snippet) in conjunction with the Q&A feature on in the provider.